# LINQ to model grouping

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I am trying to group multiple items according to several columns from my database view. I have combed through countless posts covering this topic and have had no luck in solving my issue.

Here is an example view definition:

|CustomerID|OrderID|Product|

Here is some sample data:

```
CustomerID|OrderID|Product
    1     |  123  | Apple
    1     |  123  | Pear
    1     |  124  | Apple
```

Here is what I want to achieve in my json:

```
CustomerID: 1
OrderIDs: [
  {OrderID: 123,
  Product: [
    Apple,
    Pear
  ]},
  {OrderID: 124,
  Product: [
    Apple
  ]}
]
```

These are my classes

```
class CustomerOrders
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<OrderIDs> OrderID;
}

class OrderIDs
{
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public int Product { get; set; }
}
```

And my Linq :

```
.Select(co => new CustomerOrders
{
 CustomerID = co.CustomerID
 OrderIDs = co.Select(o => new OrderID
 {
   OrderID = o.OrderID
   Product = o.Product
 }
}
```

But this returns the following json:

```
CustomerID: 1
OrderIDs: [
  {
  OrderID: 123,
  Product: [
    Apple,
    Pear
  ]},
  OrderID: 123,
  Product: [
    Apple,
    Pear
  ]},
  {OrderID: 124,
  Product: [
    Apple
  ]}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are already some problems on your classes, for example Product is set to int whereas it should be an IEnumerable .
And the problem is that you did not use GroupBy in your Linq.

Here is my result :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var data = new[]
    {
        new DbRow { CustomerId = 1, OrderId = 123, Product = "Apple" },
        new DbRow { CustomerId = 1, OrderId = 123, Product = "Pear" },
        new DbRow { CustomerId = 1, OrderId = 124, Product = "Apple" }
    };

    var resultFullLinq = data.GroupBy(row => row.CustomerId)
        .Select(groupCustomer => new CustomerOrder
        {
            Id = groupCustomer.Key,
            Orders = groupCustomer.GroupBy(row => row.OrderId)
                .Select(groupOrder => new Order
                {
                    Id = groupOrder.Key,
                    Products = groupOrder.Select(row => row.Product).ToList()
                }).OrderBy(order => order.Id).ToList()
        }).ToList();

    // OR use methods

    var resultMethods = data.GroupBy(row => row.CustomerId).Select(groupCustomer => CreateCustomerOrder(groupCustomer)).ToList();
}

private static CustomerOrder CreateCustomerOrder(IGrouping<int, DbRow> groupCustomer)
{
    return new CustomerOrder
    {
        Id = groupCustomer.Key,
        Orders = GetOrderIds(groupCustomer).OrderBy(order => order.Id).ToList()
    };
}

private static IEnumerable<Order> GetOrderIds(IGrouping<int, DbRow> groupCustomer)
{
    return groupCustomer.GroupBy(row => row.OrderId).Select(groupOrder => GetOrderId(groupOrder));
}

private static Order GetOrderId(IGrouping<int, DbRow> groupOrder)
{
    return new Order
    {
        Id = groupOrder.Key,
        Products = groupOrder.Select(p => p.Product)
    };
}

// Class that represent a row of the database
public class DbRow
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
}

class CustomerOrder
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Order> Orders;
}

class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great.

Comment: How do I order by OrderID?

Comment: @user3711590 Add an OrderBy() before the ToList when you create the list of OrderId. I add it in my answer.

Comment: How can I make both selects expression methods and give them names like CreateCustomerOrdersVM() and call it like .Select(CreateCustomerOrdersVM) or something?

And the subselect could be like .Select(CreateOrdersByListNumber). 

Just want to make the whole thing readable.

Comment: @user3711590 I edit my answer with the full linq method "in one line" and another Linq that call 3 methods to be more readable.